# Open a form with the correct subform in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in Access that has navigation control which is made up of sub-forms. The main form is just to house the navigation control. Is it possible to create an action button on another form that can open the main form but open the correct sub-form at the same time?

My issue is I can open the main form but the sub-form is only showing the first record in the table. I would ideally like to click the button, open the main form and the correct sub-form at the same time. Is that possible?

Comment: What is a "navigation control"? A tab control? And later you write *"but the sub-form is only showing the first record in the table"* - what does have to do with opening the right subform?

Comment: @Andre Navigation control is the name of a box you can put on a form which has tabs made up of sub-forms. (Is there a way to do tabs without this?) The reason I talk about the sub-form opening the first record is I was just explaining what happens when I tried to connect a button to the main form and have it open it based on the information I'm searching for.

Comment: Whoa, that was embarrassing. :) I have never used that control.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Instead of using the navigation control feature, I used the tab control feature. Which allows me to make tabs on a form, which I can then make a button to open that form and search for a record.